# How to run CruiseControl.NET task but only after a specific task ends?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

For example I have three tasks: task1, task2, task3. How to write a [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) configuration file that runs task3 but only after task2 ends with success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CruiseControl.NET v1.5 enhances the execution of tasks using their new Sequential and Parallel tasks...

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Sequential+Task

```
<sequential continueOnFailure="false">
  <description>Example of how to run multiple tasks in sequence.</description>
  <tasks>
    <!-- Tasks defined here -->
  </tasks>
</sequential>
```

Comment: +1 I did not know this feature was added. Nice answer as long as @dario doesn't mind using the 1.5 CTP release for now

Comment: Yes, that's the caveat. It's still a CTP. I'd test it first before migrating over to the new version.

Comment: Great to hear about that, but still using 1.4 ver.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this can be done pretty easily in 2 ways:

**A) CruiseControl.NET supports what is referred to as [projectTriggers](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger):**

In order to use this approach, each task needs to be isolated into their own project configuration.  Basically, the *task3 project* monitors the build status of the *task2 project*.  When the *task2 project* successfully completes, the *task3 project* triggers a build.  To setup a projectTrigger, edit your *task3 project* definition in ccnet.config and create a trigger block as follows:

```
<triggers>
  <multiTrigger>
    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger seconds="30" />
      <projectTrigger project="task2">
        <triggerStatus>Success</triggerStatus>
      </projectTrigger>
    </triggers>
  </multiTrigger>
</triggers>
```

---

**B) Setup the order of your tasks using Nant targets instead:**

As pointed out by [Wim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725467/how-tu-run-cruisecontrol-net-task-but-after-specyfic-task-ends/1725480#1725480), you may want to consider breaking the tasks out into Nant targets instead of trying to do it in the ccnet.config.  Personally, I find this approach more comfortable only because I know Nant is good at doing just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you do that inside your [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) or MSBuild task instead, and move it out of your CruiseControl.NET configuration.

What do your tasks do? Any reason you can't move them inside your NAnt or MSBuild script?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a script file (bat, [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)) where you run the tasks and check for success.